# Material UI How to set external styles for sub-components with one main common style for the entire component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, css-in-js

I have a page made up of many sub-components. The page folder holds the page file, external styles file and each sub-components folders - which also consists of their own style.

I'm not sure how to set up an external shared common style file for all sub-components along with external styles for each of the sub-components.

Ie. `DemoStyles.js` is the common styles and `Demo.js` is where are the sub-components are called.

[image]

`Demo.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import styles from "./DemoStyles";
import Red from "./red/Red";
import Blue from "./blue/Blue";

function SharedStyles(props) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Red />
      <Blue />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

SharedStyles.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SharedStyles);
```

`DemoStyles.js`:

```
export default theme => ({
  title: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 30
  }
});
```

The `title` style is not being applied.

[image]

The `className` is set in the `Red.js` file:
[image]

---

TL;DR:
I need one common external style file to apply to all subcomponents living in one folder; and each subcomponent needs their own external style specific to it.

Here is the code sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/rypoqk07lo

---

SOLVED: 
I solved this by importing the demoStyles into the RedStyles.js file and then calling it with the spread operator and passing theme as an argument like so:

`RedStyles.js`

```
import demoStyles from "../DemoStyles";
export default theme => ({
...demoStyles(theme),
red: {
backgroundColor: "red"
}
});
```

code sample updated as well

Comment: maybe since you're importing "styles" from DemoStyles.js you should export "styles" from DemoStyles.js vs "theme"?

Comment: Your `title` styles are not applied, because you don't use your `classes` prop. You can find an example here: https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#api

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pass the classes props on `Demo.js` to your components like you do on `<Red />` and `<Blue />`.

```
const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Red classes={classes} />
      <Blue classes={classes} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```

Its good to remember that **Material-UI** has [themes support](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/). It's better to use it on `Demo.js` depending of what you trying to do.

Comment: Perfect! I am using theme support as well but didn't set that up in the demo code sample. I have a lot of components and a couple of customized themes; breaking up the styles per component along with customized theme support seems to make the most sense as of now.

Comment: hmm it doesn't seem to like that. works with errors:

Warning: Material-UI: the key `title` provided to the classes property is not implemented in SimpleCard. You can only override one of the following: red.

Comment: Humm, have you checked on your https://codesandbox.io/s/rypoqk07lo ? It works there. Are you using the same material-ui version of your example? And could you share your `<SimpleCard /> component? ;)

Comment: so check out this link: https://rypoqk07lo.codesandbox.io/ and open the inspector and you will see the errors. It does work, just with errors. 
The `<SimpleCard/>` component are the sub-components in my sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/rypoqk07lo. Ie. Go to `blue` folder and it's the `blue.js` file. Same for `red.js` I can't paste the code here, too long.

Comment: I got rid of the error by adding a `title` class to the `RedStyles.js` but this is not a good fix. I asked on the material-ui github page as well.